# Tail stops tailing in sidecar Pod (K8s)

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I'm following a lab from A Cloud Guru where I had to create a Busybox container writing to a log file, and another Busybox image reading the log file and outputting it to `stdout`.

Nothing too difficult, except `kubectl logs -f` would always just return the first line of the log, and then.. nothing.

My Pod definition isn't anything special:

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: logging-sidecar
  namespace: baz
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: logger
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'while true; do date > /output/output.log; sleep 5; done']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: share-vol
      mountPath: '/output'
  - image: busybox
    name: sidecar
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'tail -F /input/output.log']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: share-vol
      mountPath: '/input'
  volumes:
  - name: share-vol
    emptyDir: {}
```

Effectively, the container creating the log file runs this command:

```
sh -c 'while true; do date > /output/output.log; sleep 5; done'
```

And the sidecar runs this command:

```
tail -F /input/output.log
```

When I change the logger to `append` (`>>`) instead of `overwrite` (`>`) everything works perfectly fine, every 5 seconds the `kubectl logs -f` command shows the new line appearing as it should.

Why does the `tail -F` option not work here?
Is there perhaps an issue with the `tail` command in this specific `busybox` version (v1.36.1)?

Changing the `sidecar` to the `alpine` image does the same as above;
However changing the image to `debian` seems to fix things, returning the output:

```
Sat Sep 16 17:38:07 UTC 2023
tail: /input/output.log: file truncated
Sat Sep 16 17:38:12 UTC 2023
tail: /input/output.log: file truncated
Sat Sep 16 17:38:17 UTC 2023
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed - from `man busybox`:

```
tail
tail [OPTIONS] [FILE]...

Print last 10 lines of each FILE to standard output. With more than one FILE, precede each with a header giving the file name. With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Options:

        -c N[kbm]       Output the last N bytes
        -n N[kbm]       Print last N lines instead of last 10
        -f              Output data as the file grows
        -q              Never output headers giving file names
        -s SEC          Wait SEC seconds between reads with -f
        -v              Always output headers giving file names
If the first character of N (bytes or lines) is a '+', output begins with the Nth item from the start of each file, otherwise, print the last N items in the file. N bytes may be suffixed by k (x1024), b (x512), or m (1024^2).
```

Busybox' tail doesn't have an option to follow truncated files.

Comment: Hm weird that it accepts the `-F` option, wonder if it's coded to just turn all options to lowercase. At least the mystery is solved.